# Unusual RewriteCond behavior

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've these lines in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*ddl=([^;]+);\sddc=([^;]+).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 =%2
RewriteRule .* index.php?ddc=%2&ddl=%1 [L]
```

`%{HTTP_COOKIE}` conaitns `ddl=123456; ddc=123456`.

When I go through a URL it doesn't work as expected above. But if I change second line to `RewriteCond %1 !=%2` it goes to `index.php`. In that file I did a `var_dump($_GET)` and output was this:

```
array(2) { ["ddc"]=> string(6) "123456" ["ddl"]=> string(6) "123456" }
```

My question is that, so why `RewriteCond %1 =%2` doesn't work as it should!

Comment: You can't use `%1`, `%2` etc in `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @anubhava The %1 or %2 backreferences a previously captured group in a rewrite cond.

Comment: Yes I know but on LHS you cannot use `%1`

Comment: @anubhava then how can I compare them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `%1`, `%2` etc in `RewriteCond`. Try this code for back referencing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*ddl=([^;]+);\sddc=\1.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?ddc=%2&ddl=%1 [L]
```